# django-import-export to export subset of fields

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-import-export

I'm using django-import-export to export users from the django user admin interface.

I want to limit the number of fields present in the export.

Looking at [the docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#customize-resource-options), I tried the following:

```
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class UserAdmin(ExportMixin, UserAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

From the python shell, this appears to work fine, the following code

```
export = UserResource().export()
print export.csv
```

produces output that contains only the 3 fields I requested.

However, exports from the admin interface still contain all User fields.

How can I limit the number of fields exported through the admin interface?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I needed to RTFM...I found the answer in the [docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration).

Assigning `resource_class` within the `UserAdmin` did the trick:

```
class UserAdmin(ExportMixin, UserAdmin):
    resource_class = UserResource
    pass
```

Huzzah.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
exclude = ('abc','def', 'ijk')
```

Assume you want to export only 'first_name' & 'last_name'. Then,

```
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        exclude = ('email')
```